# In the following proof sketch, how Eq (9) and Eq(10) are rewritten?

Tags: cryptography

I am trying to understand the UF-CMA and UF-NMA proof sketch of Dilithium Signature Scheme. I can't understand how the authors have used the outputs of the helping function to rewrite Eq (9) and Eq (10).

> [image: Helping Functions]

> [image: Lemma 1]

> [image: Equations]

Comment: In (10) simply $u'=ct_0+u$ right?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working a fair amount with Dilithium myself, however in the [version of the article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/633.pdf) I use. The equations look like this:
[image]

I do not know why the $2\gamma$ at the beginning of eq. 9 is there in your version. However, I believe the norm of **u** carries the higher order bits retrieved through the hint **h**, and that eq. 9, is then rewritten by the first bulletpoint of lemma 1, just not in great detail.

For eq. 10, I believe @Benjamin Wang is right.

I would also recommend using the [Cryptography Stack Exchange community](https://crypto.stackexchange.com), I believe you would have a higher chance of finding someone to help you with this problem there.